# How can I open a *.cer file with FileInputStream --Android

Tags: android, ssl, certificate, android-resources

At this moment I'm trying to add some certificates to Keystore,because I need that Okthpp accepts this certs.

So, Looking in developer android I saw this example: https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl.html?hl=es#HttpsExample

IN the example they do this:

```
// Load CAs from an InputStream
// (could be from a resource or ByteArrayInputStream or ...)
CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
// From https://www.washington.edu/itconnect/security/ca/load-der.crt
InputStream caInput = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("load-der.crt"));
Certificate ca;
```

What I've done, is try to load the cert from `.../res/raw/xxxxx*cer`file I added into project structure.

So my code looks like:

```
CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
caInput1 = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(String.valueOf(ctx.getResources().openRawResourceFd(R.raw.xxxx))));
```

But when I try it, doesnt work:

[image]

How can I solve it? OR is not possible ?

Answer (score 2):

The openRawResourceFd(R.raw.xxxx) fails with this kind of file, it is mentioned about it:

> This function only works for resources that are stored in the package
>        * as uncompressed data, which typically includes things like mp3 files
>        * and png images.

however you can use instead

```
InputStream is = ctx.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.xxxx);
```

this doesn't necessary use the FileInputStream, but you get the InputStream of it directly.

Comment: It says the same :/

Comment: I updated the answer, I believe its failing due to the openRawResourceFd

Comment: This code can get crt file, but when put it into raw folder, hacker can get it, so how can we get crt file from string value folder ?